# Alter granularity in date exposed filter from Y-m to Y if only year is selected

Tags: views, datetime, forms

I am trying desperately to get the following working:

**Goal**:
I have a views that displays a list of events. To this views is a date exposed filter attached, with granularity Y-m(year month). I want this filter to filter with Y granularity if only the year is selected, and by Y-m if both are selected.
In addition to that, the view is set so that: when no date filter is selected, then filter by upcoming events, else, use the exposed filter value

**Issue**:

The month is required, even if I alter the form
I am suprised by the fact that exposed_form_alter as well as the validation fct are called multiple times, before the view is pre-build and before it is pre-executed, but this might be normal behavior.
See here: http://cl.ly/image/1C0t3Z3O0D3W (hook_views_*** dpms the function's name)

**Draft**:

The solution was inspired by [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85399/views-alter-date-field-granularity-on-exposed-filter-mid-request)

```
function lezoo_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-teaser-list-panel-pane-1')
  {
   $form['#validate'][] = 'lezoo_views_exposed_form_validate';

  }
}

function lezoo_views_exposed_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {

  $handlers = &$form_state['input'];
  foreach ($handlers as $key => $handler) {
    if (
      isset($form[$key]['value']['#type'])
      && $form[$key]['value']['#type'] == 'date_select'
      && $form[$key]['value']['#date_format'] == 'Y-m'
      && $form_state['input'][$key]['value']['month'] == '') {
      $form[$key]['value']['#date_format'] == 'Y';
    unset($form[$key]['value']['#granularity'][2]);
    unset($form_state['input'][$key]['value']['month']);
  }
}
dpm('form validation');
   // dpm($form);
   // dpm('form_state');
   // dpm($form_state);
}


function lezoo_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  //If a date was selected in the exposed filter, ignore the default date filter '> today'
  $conditions = $view->query->where['1']['conditions'];
  $date_index = 3;
  if(isset($view->query->where['1']['conditions'][$date_index]) &&
    //if a date exposed filter was set
   $view->query->where['1']['conditions'][$date_index]['field'] != 'node.nid')
  {
    unset($view->query->where['1']['conditions'][2]);
  }
}
```

I am really stuck here, IRC is not helping unfortunately, and i would really appreciate more insights on this!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up going the very ugly way.

First, my module is now reduced to:

```
    function lezoo_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  //If a date was selected in the exposed filter, ignore the default date filter '> today'
  $conditions = $view->query->where['1']['conditions'];
  $date_index = 3;
  dpm($conditions);
  if(isset($view->query->where['1']['conditions'][$date_index]) &&
    //if a date exposed filter was set
   $view->query->where['1']['conditions'][$date_index]['field'] != 'node.nid')
  {
    unset($view->query->where['1']['conditions'][2]);
  }
}
```

which is needed because the default filter on dates(not exposed) is **after today**, but if you select a date, then ignore that filter.

And I added a second date_exposed_filter, so that I now have date1->granularity:Y, and date2->granularity:Y-m. I then use css to hide the Y of Y-m, and js to mirror both Year fields. if anyone is interested, here is the code I use:

```
            var year = $('.views-widget-filter-field_date_value_2 select.date-year');
            var ymonth = $('.views-widget-filter-field_date_value_1 select.date-month');
            var yearm = $('.views-widget-filter-field_date_value_1 select.date-year');

            ymonth.change(function(e){
                var value = $(this).val();
                //var value = e.target.value;
                var empty = value == "";
                if(!empty)
                {
                    yearm.val(year.val()).trigger("chosen:updated");
                }
                else
                {
                    yearm.val("");
                }
            });

            year.change(function(e){
                if(ymonth.val() != '')
                {
                    yearm.val(year.val()).trigger('chosen:updated');
                }
                else
                {
                    month.val('');
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread now, but I encountered a similar problem and ended up breaking apart the date field to solve it. The solution has been working well and opened up other opportunities across the site to select and search content by any date combination.

My original question and answer is here: [How to create a filter in Views for filtering dates by day, month, or year?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195964/how-to-create-a-filter-in-views-for-filtering-dates-by-day-month-or-year)